# For Loop: can the end value come from the value of a variable?

Tags: for-loop, stata

I have a `forvalues` loop:

```
forvalues x = 1(1)50 {
   /* Code goes here */
}
```

Instead of `50`, ideally, I would like that value to come as follows. I have a variable `name`.  Let `length = length(name)`. Whatever the largest value is for `length`, I would like that to be in place of the `50`. I could not figure how to write a `forvalues` loop in which the end point was not directly stated numerically.

I am thinking that I could deduce the maximum length of the variable as follows:

```
gen id = 1
gen length = length(name)
by id, sort: egen maxlength = max(length)
```

From there though I do not know how to store this value into the `for` loop.

Alternatively, would this be better coded by a `while` loop?

Something like:

```
gen x = 1
while (x <= maxlength) {
   /* Same Code Here */
   replace x = x + 1
}
```

Comment: Doesn'nt local limit = 50 (or whatever upper bound) work? You could then do forvalues x=1(1)limit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the trick with Stata which I think may work for you. I am using the data auto from Stata datasets.

```
sysuse auto
```

Suppose the variable `name` here be `price`. Now you want the length of variable price.

```
sum price 
gen length=r(N)
```

To see what is `r(N)` type `return list` after running the `sum price`.

In your loop it goes like follows: **(Updated as per @Nick)**

```
forvalues x = 1/`r(N)'{
   /* Code goes here */
}
```

OR:

```
 local length=r(N)
   forvalue i=1/`length'{

  dis "`i'" 
   }
```

**Note**: It is not clear why you want `for loop`.So my answer is restricted to what you only asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation I've read, it is possible to use macros but with the caveat that changing the end of the range within the forvalues loop has no effect on the number of times the loop will occur.  For instance, if length(name) is 50 when the forvalues loop starts, and you change the length of name within the loop, it will still only loop 50 times.

Technically, you'd be better off using a while loop since forvalues was intended to be used when the end of the range is a literal value.  You *can* use a forvalues loop, but you *should* use a while loop.

Here's my source to back this up:
http://www.stata.com/manuals13/pforvalues.pdf

Specifically:

> Technical note
>   It is not legal syntax to type
>   . scalar x = 3
>   . forvalues i = 1(1)`x' {
>   2. local x =`x' + 1
>   3. display `i'
>   4. }
>   forvalues requires literal numbers. Using macros, as shown in the following technical note, is
>   allowed.

And:

> Using macros, as shown in the following technical note, is
>   allowed.
>   Technical note
>   The values of the loop bounds are determined once and for all the first time the loop is executed.
>   Changing the loop bounds will have no effect. For instance,
>   will not create an infinite loop. With `n' originally equal to 3, the loop will be performed three
>   times.

```
local n 3

 forvalues i = 1(1)`n' {

 local n = `n' + 1

display `i'

}

Output:

1

2

3
```

Answer (score 2):

@Metrics' first code won't quite work. Here is a better way, cutting out what I call the middle macro.

Start with something more like

```
  . su price, meanonly 
  . forval j = 1/`r(N)' {
```

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent approach to the one proposed by @Nick and @Metrics is the following:

```
sysuse auto, clear

count if !missing(price)

forvalues x = 1 / `r(N)' {
   /* Code goes here */
}
```